# VSTO Outlook 2010: customize calendar arrangment / view

Tags: calendar, vsto, outlook-2010

I'm wondering if it is possible to program a customized calendar view (e.g. show 3 Months at once) as I find surprisingly little resources about this question.

Comment: it is possible somehow: [Outlook Year View 2.5](https://outlook-year-view.soft32.com) but I want it FOOS. A workaround what strikes me is an additional pane and add a web browser control what displays a [HTML calendar](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/how-to-view-a-yearly-calendar/) but [replace IE engine](https://fullcalendar.io/) as IE11 is too old. Even better would be to implement [JavaScript but it isn't available for office 2010](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office) in order to implement a calendar such as [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io).